# Torchvision normalize - how it operates on tuple of means/sds?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I don't understand how this transform works from torchvision. Ultimately I want to build a custom normalize class so I need to figure out how this works first.

Here in the docs it describes the init like this:

```
def __init__(self, mean, std, inplace=False):
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std
        self.inplace = inplace
```

And when I pass these parameters usually (not custom class) I pass them as a list or tuple for each channel:

`transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])`

But if I look at the call:

`return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)`

All this passes the tuple to is F.normalize() which only accepts a single value for the p parameter.

The class must iterate through the channels somehow to allow this to be implemented but how does it do this and how can I implement it in custom class?

Based on [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html), I would describe it like this:

```
class Normalize(object):
    """Convert ndarrays in sample to Tensors."""

    def __init__(self, mean, std, inplace=False):
        self.mean = mean
        self.std = std
        self.inplace = inplace

    def __call__(self, sample):
        image, landmarks = sample['image'], sample['landmarks']
        return {'image': F.normalize(image, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace),
                'landmarks': landmarks}
```

But this does not work because it does not go through each channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `normalize` function called in there is this one https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L191

The input is a tensor of shape `(C, H, W)` and `mean` and `std` can be sequences, that are internally converted to tensors. The normalization is done through broadcasting [in this way](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L217):

`tensor.sub_(mean[:, None, None]).div_(std[:, None, None])`

Comment: Oh, wow that is so confusing because torch has its own functional class that is usually called as `F.normalize` in the same way. Thanks

Comment: yes, `torchvision` and `torch` both have their own functional interface.